# Prevent linebreak of floated elements

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a header of a website that has the logo left aligned, a navigation div that is 960px wide and centered and a log in area that is right aligned. 
Here is a screen shot of my progress
[image]

The issue is that the login breaks to a new line and I don't know how to prevent it. Floating the elements doesn't work.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7UN4/)

But it doesnt produce the same results I'm seeing when I run it locally.

HTML

```
<div id="header"><!-- Outside Container, Holds Logo and Log In -->
        <div id="logoHolder">
            <p>logo</p>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <p>navigation</p>
        </div>
        <div id="loginHolder">
            <p>login</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/*Header Options*/
#header{
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    height:125px;
}
    #logoHolder{
        float:left;
    }
    #navigation{

        width:960px;
        background-color:blue;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

    #loginHolder{
        float:right;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-order your HTML to the following (move `loginHolder` above `navigation`) and it works fine:

```
<div id="header">
    <!-- Outside Container, Holds Logo and Log In -->
    <div id="logoHolder">
        <p>logo</p>
    </div>
    <div id="loginHolder">
        <p>login</p>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <p>navigation</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t7UN4/1/)**

Comment: Quick and easy solution. Thank you sir. Will accept in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to be careful with widths. The navigation width is overwhelming the other divs. And, if I'm not mistaken, div has a built in line break.  the answer above has one solution, I played with a couple edits also: you can copy in this css:

/*Header Options*/

## header {

```
width:100%;
background-color:green;
height:125px;
```

}

## logoHolder {

```
width: 100px;
background-color: red;
float:left;
```

}

## navigation {

```
width:344px;
background-color:blue;
float:left;
```

}

## loginHolder {

```
width:100px;
background-color:yellow;
float:left;
```

}